# bitcoin adresss in my email from 2014

Tags: email

i did a search in my email for "bitcoin" and i came up with a bitcoin address sent from me to me looking like this "bitcoin:1AQhW**************" is that bitcoin money and if so how do i get it ?

Answer (score 1):

That's just a bitcoin address, it may not have any bitcoins sent to it, and even if it does, you can't spend them unless you find the private key too. Check the balance of that address here https://blockchain.info